# Is it better to play the keyboard standing or sitting?

Tags: keyboard, performing, keyboard-pedals

I recently purchased a [Yamaha FC7](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/accessories/footcontrollers/fc7/?mode=model) foot pedal. I plan to use it for overall volume control, emphasizing breaks and solos. This poses a challenge, though, as I normally stand when playing the keyboard. It is possible but feels a little awkward and tiring to stand mostly on the foot that I sustain with keeping the other foot on the volume control.

**So, my question is, it is better to stand or sit?** My biggest concern is if it appears better to the audience to stand. I'm confident I can I figure out a way to stand (it is my preference), but if there really aren't any advantages to standing, it would obviously be easier to play sitting (which could have another advantage of helping being relaxed when playing).

Are there better ways to manage two pedals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will always be easier to sit and operate pedals - the required uneven shift in weight from one foot to the other and holding it for extended periods can become quite tiring.

If your biggest concern is how it looks to the audience then yes, you'll probably have to put up with the discomfort and awkward stance of standing but there are a couple of things you can do to help:

- Make sure the keyboard is set at a comfortable height (certainly don't leave it at sitting height!) and place the pedals relative to your playing position such that you don't have to lean excessively to operate them. If they're too far forward, you'll find yourself leaning backwards.
- Use a bar stool or similar behind you to 'lean' against. That way, you can appear to be standing but you also have the support of a seat. Make sure it's sturdy and not on a slippery floor, else it may let you down when you come to rely on it!
- If you're using a volume/expression pedal, get a 'balanced' one that holds its position so you don't have to keep your foot on it unless you're moving it.

Answer (score 0):

I both play guitar and keyboard and I ran into the same problem with pedals. It does not matter if you stand or sit just do what is comfortable.